# Add double[] to to custom stack in C#

Tags: c#, stack

My problem is that I cannot push a double[] to my custom stack.

```
if (int.TryParse(item[0], out intTemp))
{
   customStack.Push(parts.Skip(1).Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
}
else if(double.TryParse(item[0], out doubleTemp))
{
customStack.Push(parts.Skip(1).Select(double.Parse).ToArray());
}
```

The first if statement works, but the second gives me an exception - **CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double[]' to 'int'.**

The problem is I'm not even trying to add a 'double[]' into 'int'.

Here is my **Push method**:

```
public void Push(params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            this.stackData.Add(item);
            Console.WriteLine($"Element {item} added to stack.");
        }
    }
```

**Help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Can you most a [mcve] which reproduces that error please? We don't know what type `T` is, for instance.

Comment: It looks like the `T` in your `Push` method is an `int`, not a `double`. In that case you'll have a stack of ints. How do you propose to push a double onto your stack of ints?

Comment: No error to be found: https://dotnetfiddle.net/okJnP8

Comment: @RandRandom I'm sure the `T` comes from the generic class declaration, so your code is not the same as OP's. But OP didn't actually post it, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @RandRandom You have assumed that the signature is `Push<T>`, whereas the OP's code is just `Push`, strongly implying that the `T` is part of the signature of the stack class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`customStack` seems to be a `CustomStack<int>`. So your `Push` method expects a `params int[]` argument.

`parts.Skip(1).Select(double.Parse).ToArray()` returns a `double[]` that the compiler is now trying to convert into the first element of the `int[] items` parameter, which leads to your error message.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was simple: i was trying to add double[] to my object customStack, which is a new CustomStack from ints.

Comment: @AlexanderSvilarov If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (and also upvote it!)